# Structure of asp.net with web api and mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a question about the structure of asp.net website, especially back-end stuff

Currently, I have sql database, web api controller and mvc controller.
I have been using web api for getting or posting data to database, and using mvc controller for directing webpage.

What I want to do is as followings

It is basically registration process

1. call web api method to post user email and password from mvc controller
2. web api controller processes the user email and password, using stored procedures and functions
3. if the user email already exists in the database, web api returns some custom status code? to let the mvc controller know that.

Here is problem, since the web api will be used by other devices as well so I can't directly do some business logic for dealing with the duplication of email. So I just want to let somehow the MVC controller know the error and do some business logic.

How can I do that?, Is it fine to return some status code like 101, 201 to MVC controller? then How can I do that??

Thanks guys

Comment: First: why do you want to use your WebApi to dealing with database, second: you can do the logic of email duplication in SP it self and return message.

Comment: I am not sure cause I am pretty new to web development, But I just want to make web api kind of public? so that any other devices like mobile phones can get data from it. Then I think the api should do some sort of database stuff? I am not sure ha

Comment: Just Let me know if anything is wrong

Comment: http://imgr.es/3D02

Comment: @Div Thanks for your quick response, um can you explain a bit more? I really want to understand the business layer part. Is the business layer sending data back to both controllers? I am a bit confused..

Comment: Yeah, it's just a kind of service layer, which can call from any other web project, just use DI *(dependency injection)* properly to resolve dependency

Comment: @Div so in real world, most asp.net website only uses either mvc controller or web api controller? Sorry to keep asking ha, cause I am pretty confused about structure of asp.net...

Comment: It's all okay, ask questions is the actual use of SO. In real world, it depends...some of developers use mvc project to maintain websites only and webapi for consume data trough mobile application.

Comment: @Div one last question haha, so if I only use mvc controller for my website, the structure would be like "database - database access layer - controller - view layer, using model or data transfer object"?

Comment: Yeah, exactly! that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Use standard HttpResponse with a code from [public enum HttpStatusCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx)
Under the link you'll find the list of all codes and some examples how to use and consume them;

for example, in your API controller may return:

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
```

and then on the consumer side you'll have to handle that error.